# a href 'on click' not executing JQuery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

**Question Background:**

I am trying to pass two parameters (product name and price) from a View to an 'AddToCart' method on my MVC Controller. I'm doing this by passing the parameters to a JQuery Ajax function.

**Issue:**

Currently when clicking the 'Add To Cart' button 'link' the script is not being triggered. There is no error but the process is not taking place.

Here is the code:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>

//View:
<h3 class="panel-title boldFeatures" id="name">@((ViewBag.data as List<LoginTest.Models.HomePageItem>).First().ProductName)</h3>

<p id="price">@((ViewBag.data as List<LoginTest.Models.HomePageItem>).First().productPrice)</p>

<a class="btn btn-primary btn-block" id="addToCart">Test</a>



//Script:
<script>
    $("#addToCart").on('click',function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            url: '/HomePage/AddToCart',
            data: { name: $('#name').text(), qty: $('#price').text() },
        });

    });
</script>



//Method on controller:
 public void AddToCart(string name, string qty)
    {
       //Logic for adding to the cart.
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removed the trailing comma after data object. 
Also added `POST` method to your ajax call.

```
   <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" id="addToCart">Test</a>



    //Script:
    <script>
        $("#addToCart").on('click',function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $.ajax({
                url: '/HomePage/AddToCart',
                type: 'POST',
                data: { name: $('#name').text(), qty: $('#price').text() }
            });

        });
    </script>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/134845/href-attribute-for-javascript-links-or-javascriptvoid0

Comment: @Tracker1 Thanks for the link! Learn something new every day :}

Answer (score 0):

```
...
<a class="btn btn-primary btn-block" id="addToCart" href="javascript:void(0);">Test</a>

...
$("#addToCart").click(function(e){
  $.ajax({
    url: '/HomePage/AddToCart',
    data: { name: $('#name').text(), qty: $('#price').text() } // ,
});

...
```

Comment: They already have a preventDefault on the click event. That's just muddying up the markup.

Comment: The markup change explicitly indicates that it should never function client-side... If there's an error in the bind method, or something above the bind method, then the preventDefault will fail.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/134845/href-attribute-for-javascript-links-or-javascriptvoid0